# Drools error after migrating from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, drools, java-11, jboss-rules

I am getting following error when compiling rules after migrating from Java 8 to 11:

> Error compiling rule package at org.tolven.rules.PackageCompiler (line 68)
> Caused by: wrong class format at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2 (line 260)
> Caused by: null at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader (line 329)

Application using the following jars & running on WildFly-16:

```
jboss-rules.drools-compiler-4.0.7.jar
jboss-rules.core-compiler-3.2.3.v_686_R32x.jar
```

Any idea about what caused this issue?

Comment: ... Drools 4? Seriously? I'm impressed you got it running on Java 8 in the first place.

Comment: It worked same as in Java 7 in Java 8. No issues faced but getting the above issue in Java 11.

Comment: it's ecj issue (drools dependency) take a look at https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-329?_sscc=t it's applied to 5.5 anyway may workout for you

Comment: @pejas thanks! Yes, after upgrading to ecj-3.27.0.jar, class format error gone but facing error "Unable to create Field Extractor" with drools 4.0.7.

Comment: Any solution on this. I am getting FieldExtractor for same set of libraries?